# Project Structure for Python projects with MySQL queries?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a Python project that makes a variety of MySQL queries, which take some variables and insert them into the query itself. So for example:

```
number_of_rows = 50
query1 = '''select *
from some_db
limit %s''' % (number_of_rows)
```

However, since I have a lot of long queries, within a script that manipulates and cleans the data, it's making my script less readable. What is a reasonable way to structure my program so that it is both readable and makes these query calls? One way that has worked so far is to have another python file, let's call it my_query_file.py, with something along the lines of

```
def my_first_query(number_of_rows):
    query1 = '''select *
    from some_db
    limit %s''' % (number_of_rows)
    return query
```

and then importing my_query_file from within my main project file, and calling my_first_query. Is there a better way to do this, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider using existing query builder like python-sql:

https://code.google.com/p/python-sql/

or if the complexity of your application justifies that you might try full blown ORM like SQL Alchemy:

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using a template system like Jinja2? I've used it to store and use templates for a variety of situations (ranging from web development to automatic code generation) and it works very well.

You could have your SQL queries in template files, and load and *fill* them as you wish.

Comment: I wonder why I get downvoted. He was asking for a way of storing SQL statements separately, not for a full-fledged ORM.

Comment: Also a good suggestion, shame that I can't mark two answers as correct!